# vb 6.0 can anyone help me with my code?

Tags: mysql, vb6

Im working with my project inventory system i want to display the filtered dates in my books table in the mysql in my listview1 using 2 DTPicker and make a report for it. Im having an error in my query in  the classmodule idk if its only the query and im really confused im a begginer in vb 6.0...please in need your help guys.

Im using 2 tables namely books and supplier.

MY CODE IN THE 'CLASS MODULE':

```
Sub DisplayList(ListView1 As ListView, DateFrom As Date, DateTo As Date)
Dim lstItem As ListItem, a As Integer
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String
If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close

sql = " SELECT supplier.category,books.title,books.dataAcquired,books.amount,books.quantity,books.accesionno,books.conditions" & _
      " From supplier INNER JOIN books" & _
      " ON supplier.code=books.code" & _
      " WHERE (((books.dataAcquired)>=#" & DateFrom & "#) and ((books.dataAcquired) <=#" & DateTo & "#))" & _
      " GROUP BY supplier.category,books.title,books.dataAcquired,books.amount,books.quantity,books.accesionno,books.conditions" & _
      " ORDER BY books.dataAcquired DESC;"
   rs.Open sql, cnn

   ListView1.ListItems.Clear
   Do While Not rs.EOF
    a = a + 1
        Set lstItem = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , a, 1, 1)
            lstItem.SubItems(1) = rs(0).Value
            lstItem.SubItems(2) = rs(1).Value
            lstItem.SubItems(3) = rs(2).Value
            lstItem.SubItems(4) = rs(3).Value
            lstItem.SubItems(5) = rs(4).Value
            lstItem.SubItems(6) = rs(5).Value
            lstItem.SubItems(7) = rs(6).Value
            rs.MoveNext
            Loop

End Sub
```

MY CODE IN MY FORM:

```
Private Sub Show_Click()
clsData.DisplayList ListView1, DTPicker1.Value, DTPicker2.Value
lblCount.Caption = ListView1.ListItems.Count
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
DTPicker1.Value = Date
DTPicker2.Value = Date
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Activate()
clsData.DisplayList ListView1, DTPicker1.Value, DTPicker2.Value
lblCount.Caption = ListView1.ListItems.Count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Change # by '

```
format date how yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMdd

sql = " SELECT supplier.category,books.title,books.dataAcquired,books.amount,books.quantity,books.accesionno,books.conditions" & _
  " From supplier INNER JOIN books" & _
  " ON supplier.code=books.code" & _
  " WHERE (((books.dataAcquired)>='" & format(DateFrom,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "') and ((books.dataAcquired) <='" & format(DateTo,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'))" & _
  " GROUP BY supplier.category,books.title,books.dataAcquired,books.amount,books.quantity,books.accesionno,books.conditions" & _
  " ORDER BY books.dataAcquired DESC;"
```

change loop while added validations for recordset emptys, some how

```
 if RecordsetIsClosed(rs) then exit sub

 While Not RecordSetIsEmpty(rs)
      a = a + 1
      Set lstItem = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , a, 1, 1)
      lstItem.SubItems(1) = rs(0).Value
      lstItem.SubItems(2) = rs(1).Value
      lstItem.SubItems(3) = rs(2).Value
      lstItem.SubItems(4) = rs(3).Value
      lstItem.SubItems(5) = rs(4).Value
      lstItem.SubItems(6) = rs(5).Value
      lstItem.SubItems(7) = rs(6).Value
      rs.MoveNext
 wend

Public Function RecordSetIsEmpty(ByRef rs As ADODB.Recordset) As Boolean    
'   On Local Error GoTo RecordSetIsEmpty_Error    
'       RecordSetIsEmpty = True    
'       If rs Is Nothing Then
'           RecordSetIsEmpty = True
'           Exit Function
'       End If    
'       If RecordsetIsClosed(rs) = True Then
'           RecordSetIsEmpty = True
'           Exit Function
'       End If    
    RecordSetIsEmpty = (rs.BOF = True And rs.EOF = True)
'   RecordSetIsEmpty_Done:
'       Exit Function
'   RecordSetIsEmpty_Error:
'       Resume RecordSetIsEmpty_Done    
End Function


Public Function RecordsetIsClosed(ByRef rs As ADODB.Recordset) As Boolean    
On Local Error GoTo RecordsetIsClosed_Error
    RecordsetIsClosed = True    
    If rs Is Nothing Then
        RecordsetIsClosed = True
    End If        
    If rs.State <> adStateClosed Then
        RecordsetIsClosed = False
    End If
RecordsetIsClosed_Done:
    Exit Function
RecordsetIsClosed_Error:
    Resume RecordsetIsClosed_Done
End Function
```

Dont forget to open the database connection

updated thanks Mark Bertenshaw

RecordSetIsEmpty is use for problems when do movenext.. well i remember

RecordsetIsClosed is use because in some cases and databases managers return not recordset or the recordset is not correct initialized

for example access is necessary use movefist before do movenext or read values

Comment: Whilst I marked you up regarding the SQL date comparisom (which is the main problem with the code), I really don't see why you need the RecordSetIsEmpty() function. Once you have checked that the recordset is not Nothing, you can quite happily use While Not rs.EOF (or even better,  Do Until rs.EOF) as the loop condition.  Those checks per record are unnecessary, and inefficient.

Comment: updated. rs.eof sometimes failed sorry has not examples now i work with .net but i wait that serve to someone